# custom app_offline

Tags: asp.net

I'm using web deploy to publish my app on production and visual studio always create an app_offline.htm while doesn't finish the task.
How can I customize this html file ? I would like to use some template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't through Visual Studio. The only way to do it would be to manually create your own build process.